# usermod: group 'chrome-remote-desktop' does not exist [After fresh install of Chrome Remote Desktop for Linux]

Tags: google-chrome, google-cloud-platform, debian

From
https://cloud.google.com/solutions/chrome-desktop-remote-on-compute-engine

Followed all docs with no errors.

At the "Configure and Start" section:

```
sudo usermod -a -G chrome-remote-desktop $USER
```

This command returns the following error:

```
usermod: group 'chrome-remote-desktop' does not exist
```

Note: The Chrome Remote Desktop install section went without issue(s).

Should I reboot?
I assume manually creating the group is not a good idea because if the chrome remote desktop usually creates it, it probably has specific permissions that I'm not aware of.

Comment: At least you should show the contents of /etc/groups.

Comment: @U.Windl Not really... If the group doesn't exist then the installation clearly didn't happen as it should have. I have switched method on how to deploy, but the issue was with the installation which happened without error but had a package required that was not supported by the OS (Deb9) I was deploying on

Answer (score 2):

Documentation is good, because first you manually install the .deb package:

```
$ sudo  dpkg -i chrome-remote-desktop_current_amd64.deb
```

It will fail due to missing dependencies, it will tell you which dependencies are missing and you can automatically install them with apt package manager.

```
  Package xbase-clients is not installed.
 chrome-remote-desktop depends on psmisc; however:
  Package psmisc is not installed.
 chrome-remote-desktop depends on python3-psutil; however:
  Package python3-psutil is not installed.
 chrome-remote-desktop depends on libcairo2 (>= 1.2.4); however:
  Package libcairo2 is not installed.
 chrome-remote-desktop depends on libdrm2 (>= 2.4.38); however:
  Package libdrm2 is not installed.
 chrome-remote-desktop depends on libgbm1 (>= 17.1.0~rc2); however:
  Package libgbm1 is not installed.
 chrome-remote-desktop depends on libgtk-3-0 (>= 3.9.10); however:
  Package libgtk-3-0 is not installed.
 chrome-remote-desktop depends on libnspr4 (>= 2:4.9-2~); however:
  Package libnspr4 is not installed.
 chrome-remote-desktop depends on libnss3 (>= 2:3.22); however:
  Package libnss3 is not installed.
 chrome-remote-desktop depends on libpango-1.0-0 (>= 1.14.0); however:
  Package libpango-1.0-0 is not installed.
 chrome-remote-desktop depends on libx11-6; however:
  Package libx11-6 is not installed.
 chrome-remote-desktop depends on libxcb1 (>= 1.9.2); however:
  Package libxcb1 is not installed.
 chrome-remote-desktop depends on libxdamage1 (>= 1:1.1); however:
  Package libxdamage1 is not installed.
 chrome-remote-desktop depends on libxext6; however:
  Package libxext6 is not installed.
 chrome-remote-desktop depends on libxfixes3; however:
  Package libxfixes3 is not installed.
 chrome-remote-desktop depends on libxrandr2; however:
  Package libxrandr2 is not installed.
 chrome-remote-desktop depends on libxtst6; however:
  Package libxtst6 is not installed.
dpkg: error processing package chrome-remote-desktop (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for systemd (241-7~deb10u5) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 chrome-remote-desktop
```

Then is when you have to use apt to fix missing dependencies, note that **apt will automatically add chrome-remote-desktop group at the end of the installation**:

```
$ sudo apt install --assume-yes --fix-broken
```

```
Setting up chrome-remote-desktop (XX.X.XXX.XX) \
Adding group `chrome-remote-desktop' (GID 113) \
Done.
```

Next step would be to [set the X Environment](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/chrome-desktop-remote-on-compute-engine#installing_an_x_windows_system_desktop_environment).

Comment: Just skip the dpkg -install part and replace with apt install. It automatically grabs the dependencies. One line instead of two +...

Answer (score 0):

I had to install chrome remote desktop on the vm and it worked. You can find instructions here:
https://cloud.google.com/solutions/chrome-desktop-remote-on-compute-engine#installing_chrome_remote_desktop_on_the_vm_instance